# Overflow encountered in square

Tags: python, numpy, overflow

I have tried searching for the overflow error that I'm getting, but I did not succeed.

When I run this program, I get runtime errors that in no way makes any sense to me.
and here is the data i used: https://pastebin.com/MLWvUarm

```
import numpy as np

def loadData():
    data = np.loadtxt('data.txt', delimiter=',')
    x = np.c_[data[:,0:2]]
    y = np.c_[data[:,-1]]
    return x, y

def hypothesis(x, theta):
    h = x.dot(theta)
    return h

def computeCost(x, y, theta):
    m = np.size(y, 0)
    h = hypothesis(x, theta)
    J = (1/(2*m)) * np.sum(np.square(h-y))
    return J

def gradient_descent(x, y, theta, alpha, mxIT):
    m = np.size(y, 0)
    J_history = np.zeros((mxIT, 1))

    for it in range(mxIT):
        hyp = hypothesis(x, theta)
        err = hyp - y
        theta = theta - (alpha/m) * (x.T.dot(err))
        J_history[it] = computeCost(x, y, theta)

    return theta, J_history

def main():
    x, y = loadData()
    x = np.c_[np.ones(x.shape[0]), x]
    theta = np.zeros((np.size(x, 1), 1))
    alpha = 0.01
    mxIT = 400

    theta, j_his = gradient_descent(x, y, theta, alpha, mxIT)
    print(theta)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you provide the data returned by loadData()? The algorithm worked for random x and y.

BTW: Using gradient descent for simple linear regression is an overkill.

Comment: i have edited my post and updated the code. i know that GD is an overkill but it was for me to test only and thanks.
@tstanisl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After loading `x`, try to divide it by the mean and see if it converges. Link to documentation for mean: [numpy.mean](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html)

```
...
x, y = loadData()
x = x / x.mean(axis=0, keepdims=True)
x = np.c_[np.ones(x.shape[0]), x]
...
```

Currently it seems to diverge and this produces very high errors which numpy complains about. You can see this from the cost history which you maintain in `J_history`.